# Angular: Detect change in nested object

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have been looking for a solution here and elsewhere for hours and I cannot believe I haven't found one. So anyway. I have a simple Angular component (using it in Ionic 3):

```
class Item {
  name = 'New item';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'edit-item',
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]='newItem.name' /><button (click)='save()'>Save</button>`
})
export class EditItem {

  newItem = new Item();

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  save() {
    this.newItem = new Item();
  }

}
```

When I enter text in the input field, it correctly changes `item.name`. Now however when I click save, the input field continues to show the text I entered. As I created a new item, I'd rather have it display 'New Item'.

I am aware that the Angular change detection does not deep-compare objects. So I have tried to change the `save` function to:

```
save() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

I've also tried to change the component's `changeDetection` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and implement a custom `ngOnChanges` to fire `cd.markForChanges()` when the item name has changed.

I have not been successful with any of these approaches. Can you please help me find the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/O6RPBPzcQi9tW0xGB7NB?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: you have class without constructor. this.newItem=new Item() do nothing. You can use this.newItem={name=''} to change the value. NOTE:If you only have definition use interface, not class

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in a clean plunker either. Seems to be an issue with my project setup :-(